# Is there name for these two design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

**I am wondering if these would be considered two design patterns and, more importantly, what their names are.**

In this *extremely simple example*, they affectively appear to end with the same result. The primary difference is that one modifies the argument in-place while the other returns *something* based upon the argument.

**Pattern 1**

```
// Modifies the Object in-place
function foo(a):
    a.some_field += 1

foo(a)
```

**Pattern 2**

```
// A very generic implementation
function bar(int):
    return int += 1

a.some_field = bar(a.some_field)

// Or, at least a more generic implementation
function baz(a):
    a.some_field += 1
    return a

a = baz(a)
```

**Question Rationale**

The reason I ask is that I tend to follow *Pattern 2*. It's usually quite a bit more complex than this example (e.g. Text Analysis). There may be various objects of different Classes and if they contain a String, they can be ran through the libraries, usually without modifying the libraries themselves.

The main benefits I see in *Pattern 2* is that it seems more testable, generic, and easier to modularize. I've worked with developers (specifically, Java developers) who tend to go with *Pattern 1*. I'm not sure why they do but it's difficult to explain the difference between styles/design-patterns without having some good third-party documentation to reference (for both parties).

Comment: Please correct my Understanding for your Question, Is Question is closely coupled with Pass-By-Value & Pass-By-Reference ?,Thanks mate

Comment: In the example I have here, you can assume they are passed by reference; otherwise, the foo() example wouldn't end up with the correct results. I can see the confusion, though, with the integers being passed.

Comment: @Kurits: I am really sorry dude,I have also written codes same as your pattern 1 and pattern 2 respectively ,but I was unable to recollect, i thought this is a Decorator Pattern, but i m not sure it is, because In Decorator Pattern we can extended functionality of an object statically or dynamically,:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that either of these is large enough to really be called a "Design Pattern" or that either has been given a name as such, but the second is used in OO programming to enable [Method Cascading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading), which is instrumental in enabling a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

For a completely artificial example, if you have an object defined like (in Java syntax, but the same applies for other OO languages)

```
public class A {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public A foo() {
        x += 1;
        return this;
    }

    public A bar() {
        y += 1;
        return this;
    }

    public int baz() {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

You can create one object of this type and "chain" method calls together as:

```
int a = new A().foo().bar().baz();
```

While it's not required by the pattern (and isn't used in the examples in the wikipedia article referenced here), this style of API is frequently used in implementations of the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).